# Combine list items in Common Lisp (Clisp)

Tags: list, merge, clisp

I'm having trouble combining two items in a list together into one item.

For example:

```
'(Ben Hofferber) => '(Ben_Hofferber) or '(Ben-Hofferber)
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

I've been messing around with print functions trying to get it to work that way with no success.I need to combine and separate these items so that I can use them as keys for an a-list.

Comment: You should specify what the elements of the list could be and what you mean by "combine". E.g., how would you combine two symbols from different packages?

Comment: Basically I want to combine data together from two elements in a list to one element. so from '(Ben Hofferber) to '(Ben_Hofferber) where cdr will return nil instead of Hofferber.

Comment: You did not answer my question: how do you want to combine symbol cl:car with symbol cl-user::Ben?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lists as alist keys too.
E.g.,

```
(assoc '(1 2) '(((1 1) a) ((1 2) b) ((1 3) c)) :test #'equal)
==> ((1 2) B)
```

So, if you have a list of people

```
(defparameter *people* '((Ben Hofferber) (Adam Young)))
```

you can set their ages like this:

```
(defparameter *ages* (mapcar #'list *people* '(20 11)))
```

and find them like this:

```
(assoc '(Ben Hofferber) *ages* :test #'equal)
==> ((BEN HOFFERBER) 20)
```

If, however, you insist on combining symbols into one, you will have to explain how you want to do that.

If both symbols are in the same package, the combined symbols can be placed there too:

```
(defun combine-symbols (s1 s2)
  (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name s1) "-" (symbol-name s2))
          (symbol-package s1)))
```

but if they are in different packages (e.g., `cl:car` and `cl-user::ben`), you would have to make a tough choice which package to go with.

Alternatively, you can go with strings and use

```
(defun combine-objects (o1 o2)
  (format nil "~A-~A" o1 o2))
```

Don't forget to pass `:test #'equal` or `:test #'string=` to `assoc`.